# Append <li> to wordpress primary-nav custom menu

Tags: wordpress, search, menu, nav

I'm trying to learn but clearly I suck with php - how to add this:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

into the end of this (as the last list element `<li>`)???

```
<?php if(has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')): wp_nav_menu(array( > 'theme_location' => 'primary_navigation' )); endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_nav_menu_items` aren't mentioned in the codex, so there are no concrete description on how to use it.

`wp_nav_menu_items` can be found on line 347 in

> wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php

```
$items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_items', $items, $args );
```

within `wp_nav_menu`.

In the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), it states the following

> Displays a navigation menu created in the Appearance → Menus panel.

So this means that `wp_nav_menu_items` is only fired when a navigation menu is present that was created in the "menus" panel, and not on the default navigation menu. It is a design flaw in my opinion. `wp_nav_menu_items` should actually be included in the default menu as well. This is also one aspect that is not mentioned in any of the tutorials I've tested.

There is another filter that I've tested, `wp_list_pages`,  that seems to work as expected.

There is a problem with your code though as well. When I add it to the default nav bar, any searches I do sents me to my db. Actually again. I could not get proper examples to work. I eventually found this code in a plugin called [search-box-on-navigation-menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-box-on-navigation-menu/).

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
function add_search_box($items, $args) {

        ob_start();
        get_search_form();
        $searchform = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $items .= '<li>' . $searchform . '</li>';

    return $items;
    }
?>
```

For this code to work on the default nav bar, just add the following line to the code `add_filter('wp_list_pages','add_search_box', 10, 2);`, so your end code will be

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_list_pages','add_search_box', 10, 2);
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
function add_search_box($items, $args) {

        ob_start();
        get_search_form();
        $searchform = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $items .= '<li>' . $searchform . '</li>';

    return $items;
}    
?>
```

Hope this help